# MVC4 web getting the user details from wrong Active directory.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication, active-directory-group

I have MVC 4 web app deployed on 'Alpha' domain and web app is getting the Windows User details using the following code. We have trusted relationship between 3 different domains (Alpha, Beta and Gamma). When a user called `Beta\bloggs` login opens the web app following code returns the details of `alpha\bloggs`. Is there a way to get the right user from active directory.

Thanks in advance.

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["FullUserName"] = fullName;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["EmailAddress"] = user.EmailAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you should test against a global catalog.

Can you try to change you context like this :

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DNSName.Of.GlobalCatalog.com:3268", "DC=yourcompany,DC=com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Context.domain identifies the credential store to use. A connection to the correct domain would still be required to lookup information in another domain. Domain trust just specifies credential mapping, who in domain x maps to credential y in domain z.

I don't think that FindByIdentity can handle implicit domain trust lookups.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I could not understand you answer. Can you please explain. Does it mean that its not possible!

Comment: I believe that you need to connect directly to the AD server that you want to query.